# SPOJ SCUBADIV - Recursive DP Approach

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I have been trying to solve http://www.spoj.com/problems/SCUBADIV/ question at SPOJ. I have come up with a recursive DP solution.

I am using knapsack approach with a 3 dimensional array to store the number of cylinders, required oxygen weight, and nitrogen weight. At each recursive step I'm checking for the amount of oxygen and nitrogen yet to be filled.  If it is negative, it's as good as zero.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define inf 99999999

int n;
vector<int> o;
vector<int> ni;
vector<int> w;
int ow;
int nw;
int knapsack(int n,int ow,int nw);  // n - number of cylinders,ow-wt. of oxygen
                                    // nw-wt. of nitogen.
int main(){
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        int i;
        scanf("%d %d",&ow,&nw);
        scanf("%d",&n);
        o.resize(n);
        ni.resize(n);
        w.resize(n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            scanf("%d%d%d",&o[i],&ni[i],&w[i]); // o[i] storing wt. of oxygen cylinders
        int res =  knapsack(n,ow,nw);          //ni[i] storing wt. of nitrogen cylinders
        printf("%d",res);
    }
    return 0;   
}


int knapsack(int n,int ow,int nw){
    int dp[n+1][ow+1][nw+1];
    memset(dp,inf,sizeof (dp));  //setting value of array to inf to get minimum weight
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        dp[i][0][0]=0;

    if(dp[n][ow][nw]!= inf)
        return dp[n][ow][nw];
    else if (ow - o[n-1]>=0 && nw - ni[n-1]>=0)
        return dp[n][ow][nw]= min(knapsack(n-1,ow,nw),w[n-1]+knapsack(n-1,ow-o[n-1],nw-ni[n-1]));
    else if(ow -o[n-1]<0 && nw - ni[n-1] >=0)
        return dp[n][ow][nw]=min(knapsack(n-1,0,nw),w[n-1]+knapsack(n-1,0,nw-ni[n-1]));
    else if(ow-o[n-1]>=0 && nw-ni[n-1]<0)
        return dp[n][ow][nw]=min(knapsack(n-1,ow,0),w[n-1]+knapsack(n-1,ow-o[n-1],0));
    else if(ow-o[n-1]<0 && nw-ni[n-1]<0)
        return dp[n][ow][nw]= knapsack(n-1,0,0); 
}
```

This code is not giving the desired result (it's giving -1).  Is the approach correct ?

Comment: Would it be possible to describe the problem and your solution in your words? I'm having a hard time understanding the code, or even the question on that site.

Comment: You are given the required minimum volume of oxygen and nitrogen to be carried. The volume of nitrogen and oxygen cylinders are give,also the weight the cylinder associated is given. You are supposed to select the minimum weight of cylinders required to achieve the given volume of oxygen and nitrogen.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with this code:

```
int dp[n+1][ow+1][nw+1];
memset(dp,inf,sizeof (dp));
```

The `memset()` function sets a byte pattern, not a value.  Since `inf` is a larger-than-a-byte value, it is essentially doing `inf % 256` and initializing all the bytes in `dp[][][]` to that value.  This is further complicated by `dp[][][]` being of base type `int`, so 4 bytes set to the same byte value is something unexpected.

In the case of your value for `inf`, of `99999999`, the byte value will be 0xff, and so all the `int`s in `dp[][][]` will be set to -1.

I don't know if this is expected, but it looks like it could be a mistake.

Comment: what will be the better way other than memset,running 3 loops ?

Comment: @plutonium:  There is nothing wrong with running three loops.  That has the advantage of being predictable.  Perhaps after the algorithm works you can go back and look for optimization.

Comment: okay thanks, is there any flaw in the algorithm? I am not able to get

Comment: @plutonium:  While I am an experienced scuba diver, I looked for a minute at the problem, but did not understand the problem you are trying to solve.  I don't see any other obvious low-level logic flaws, but I have given no effort to the higher levels.

Answer (score 1):

Let M(x, O, N) be the minimum weight of cylinders that will provide O liters of oxygen and N liters of nitrogen by choosing from only cylinders 1 to x.  Let O(x), N(x), and W(x) be the amount of oxygen and nitrogen available in the x'th cylinder and the cylinder's weight respectively. Then either we choose to use the x'th cylinder or we don't:

```
M(x, O, N) = min( W(x) + M(x - 1, O - O(x), N - N(x)), M(x - 1, O, N) )
```

The base case occurs when we have no cylinders at all.

```
M(0, O, N) = 0 if O <= 0 and N <= 0, infinity otherwise
```

I won't be reading your unformatted, cryptically written code to figure out whether it implements this correctly.  I will say `memset` can only be used to set *bytes* to a given value. Your call is not doing what you think. Additionally, your recursive procedure returns junk if execution reaches the end of the `if` chain.

Work a small example by hand.  Run your code either in a debugger or with `printf`s inserted to show what's going on.  Figure out where its actual execution diverges from your hand calculation.

Comment: Should the base case also be when amount of nitrogen and/or oxygen falls below zero ? also I have added comments to relevant steps,sorry foe presenting the code in an unformatted manner

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to solve this problem with a recursive approach, but this is not how to do it. There are multiple problems with the code, and 'obviously' it will return -1. The question is I shall try to answer is: tell me some of the things wrong with this code.

1. Variable names like `dp` obscure the meaning of the code. Give them meaningful names!
2. Don't resize a vector and read into a pointer. Read values and push them onto the vector.
3. Print out the data to ensure you read it right.
4. The `memset` function fills with bytes, in this case -1. Use a loop to initialise ints.
5. The first `if` statement can only ever return 0 or -1 (or inf once you fix the init). As it is the other code will not be executed.
6. Assigning a value into `dp` is of no effect, since it is in automatic storage (on the stack).
7. I don't understand the chain of `if` statements. Explain them.
8. There is no `else` so the function can fall off the end.

Best to rewrite, debug, and if it still doesn't work come back with something we can read.

Comment: the if statements are used to check the volume of nitrogen and/or oxygen yet to be filled. If it is >=0 then there exits an index in the array which can store the min. wt up till that  point else if it is negative then it is as good as 0 weight to be filled. Anyway what is wrong with resizing vector and accessing it by index.

Comment: and will "fill" be a better option than"memset"

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that you use this as an opportunity to learn how to write better code using the powerful features of C++. If you have any specific questions, then you should ask a new question and I'm sure there are people happy to answer.